# Is forwarding a message to all children via an actor selection more efficient than iterating over the child ActorRefs?

Tags: java, akka

I have a scenario where when an actor receives a specific message it must forward the message to all of it's children that exist at that time.

I think I have 2 options to solve this.

```
getContext().actorSelection("*").forward(message, getContext());
```

or

```
getContext().getChildren().forEach(child -> child.forward(message, getContext()));
```

Without fully understanding the internal implementation of actor selection it's hard to know which will perform better. I plan to perform some bench marks with the kind of scale I am expecting to require but would appreciate any insight to this that experienced users may have.

Thanks

Comment: I would be inclined to think that iterating over the children would be much faster.  In order to send messages to an actor selection, the akka code must look through all actors in the system looking for matches.  If you have a very large system, this will be far less efficient than looping through a known quantity which the `children` property will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't benchmark it, but I was looking the implementation of both options. Both should be practically very similar in terms of performance, because they use an iterable of actor references ultimately.

On the other hand, you can [check](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/6728de8b3c235a27329234d984065f0bc65e9451/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorSelection.scala) that the string "*" is translated into a expression and a forward in an actorSelection will just match that expression with the children of the actor, and then forward the message to each of the matching children.

```
matchingChildren.foreach(_.tell(sel.msg, sender))
```

and do that recursively if needed (for example in "*/*").

So I would recommend to use getChildren to avoid the overload of parse the string ("*"), translate it in a regular expression, and filter the matching children.

Comment: where is the code snippet from that you have included? I assume it's scala but not sure what it does - also @cmbaxter commented above that performance would likely be different as the actor selection will scan the whole actor system where as the children iterator will be more focused. Is this your understanding also?

Comment: I edited my response in order to answer your question. But I think that "actor selection will scan the whole actor system" is not true because the selection has access to the reference of each children. It may be true if you use context.system.actorSelection(), but it's not the case.

Comment: thanks for the additional info, i agree with what you are saying. The ultimate proof will be in a benchmark which I plan to do at some point so will update with additional info as and when.

Comment: one final question, is the actor selection performed synchronously on the thread being used to process the original message, or does it get handed to processed asynchronously? Thanks

Comment: synchronous on the thread of the caller actor. But I think you can enclose it in a Future and use the callbacks: I'm not sure if that is a good idea because of the possible shared state between threads.