# Java Akka - Broadcasting Message to Child Actors from Parent Context

Tags: java, akka

```
ActorSelection selection =   context.actorSelection( "/user/ParentActor/*");
selection.tell(msg,null);
```

Assumming the parent actor context presented here in the example has more than 1 actor.

Does the above tell statement send message to all child actors  sequentially or  parallely.That is whether the  tell statement behave like a broadcastor or internally an iteration is performed to send message to each actor in the selection

Comment: I asked a very similar question the other day, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/jFs_rnhFgKA and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189059/is-forwarding-a-message-to-all-children-via-an-actor-selection-more-efficient-th for additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking [here](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/953a3165639121165db69e48ca07a4e0075743ab/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/ActorSelection.scala#L176) (which is the method called by the tell) it seems to use an iterator, so I'd say sequential.

Nonetheless, it's a quite lightweight operation, so you shouldn't worry too much about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about performance, it might be better to keep track of the actors, or to use an event bus.
In an event bus you can have the actors subscribe to a topic and then you broadcast the message through the event bus.
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/event-bus.html

You could also use a router to broadcast to all children.
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html